# What wordpress functions to use to control the theme in Admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating my first Wordpress theme, initially I would like to understand How do I control the index.php in admin?

```
<h3>Service<h3>
<img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/img/iamgeservice1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">

<h3>Service 2<h3>
<img src="<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/img/imageservice2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
```

In case each service would be a page or post, and displaying in index.php only the title and the highlighted image.

Only the services (pages or post) that are selected should appear

What Wordpress function should I use in function.php?

Comment: your question is unclear - which part of the admin do you want to control? And why?  As a starter, you don't control it through a theme.  There is no "admin theme" or "admin template".  You have to use some hooks that [remove admin widgets](https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced:_Removing_Dashboard_Widgets) or [add admin widgets](https://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API)

Comment: Thanks for replying @cale_b, please see my comment in user's answer Dev Kiran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding, you just want to display the services in the home page/ index.php file.

**Create a Post type for adding your services:**
Use this plugin for creating a new post type 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ 
or use https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

You can display the contents by using the following query, change your post type name

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'services' ) );
if($query->have_posts()) {
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();  ?>
   <h3>
     <?php the_title(); ?>
   <h3>
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I still have two problems: I read the wordpress documentation that you indicated but I did not find how to change the url of the post type `www.mysite.com/service/nameservice` to: `www.mysite.com/nameservice`- The other problem: posts created as post type do not appear in the options to add in the custom menu

Comment: 1. It's not generally advised to change the URLs of a custom post type to NOT have the "type" portion: www.mysite.com/**service**/nameservice.  That space is reserved for PAGES.  WordPress is smart, and will generally resolve the URL even if you put www.mysite.com/nameservice, but you risk slug collisions. 2. Those post types CAN be made to show in the custom menu, however you need to be sure to understand how that works: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16482/how-can-i-get-my-custom-post-types-to-appear-in-nav-menus-php-menu

Comment: Thank you @cale_b the last reply from the link you sent helped me to solve the menu issue: `in Appearance -> Menu and go to Scree Option on the top and make sure to tick the CPT UI, and it will appear.`On the url I understand what I am doing, I would like to know how to do to take away the "type" part of the url

Comment: Regardless if you "know what you are doing", this is NOT a good idea.  BUT, it can be done - to find the answer, use Google: https://kellenmace.com/remove-custom-post-type-slug-from-permalinks/

Comment: Thanks a million, With your help @cale_b I was able to solve the last two doubts